# Can I select the data in the window obtained by the function interval?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

We use the statement “group by symbol, interval(time, 1000*60*5, "null")” to get the 5 minutes’ data statistics, but the interval_time in the result table is the starting time of the window. Can I use the ending window time as interval_time?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the example code:

```py
t=table((2018.01.01T01:00:00+rand(1000,25)) join (2018.01.01T02:00:00 + rand(100,5)) as time, rand(1.0, 30) as x)
select temporalAdd(t.intervaltime,5,"m"),last_x from (select last(x) from t group by interval(time, 300, 1) as intervaltime) as t
```